# "sorry that did not work. please try again" when logging into vps

Tags: server, login, password, login-screen

I am a new ubuntu user. I have a XRDP remote desktop setup on my vps. Whenever I connect, the user is "root", but the root password does not work even thought I am putting it in 100% correct. It just says "Sorry, that did not work. Please try again.". I have tried disabling my password, all that did was make it sometimes work and sometimes not. I have tried changing the password, does nothing. I have tried creating a new user account and giving it access to .Xauthority but that account does not show up.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.203-1-pve x86_64)
I do not have much installed on the virtual desktop yet, so if required I am willing to reinstall anything.

Comment: I bought a Ubuntu VPS from a hosting provider and followed their tutorial to set up a remote desktop. I went through the ubuntu setup and was browsing firefox before I disconnected for a bit. When I reconnected it came up with the menu screen (showing the time and "Press any key to login"). I pressed a key and got to the login screen for a user named "root". It does not ask me for a username, even after I added another account from ssh. Screenshot: https://freeimage.host/i/HCkgxcX

Comment: SSH Works fine with my root login. Here is the tutorial: https://zap-hosting.com/guides/docs/en/vserver_linux_xrdp/

Comment: I use various ssh software to sign in, such as https://app.shellngn.com/ and Terminus to name a few. Once I had access to shell, I put in the commands from that tutorial and setup my virtual desktop. I use shellngn and the windows remote desktop connection to connect to my remote desktop.

Comment: I am 100% sure I am using ubuntu. Im going to try and explain this in full. I purchased a Ubuntu VPS off of a service called "zap hosting". I connected to the terminal/ssh using the IP, default username (root) and a password I set on the hosting providers panel. I followed their tutorial on how to set up a remote desktop and connected to it. I did the ubuntu set up process and then disconnected from the desktop for a bit. When I connected again, it came up with this screen: freeimage.host/i/HCkgxcX